# Makefile escaping variables in bash command to Docker container

Tags: docker, makefile, escaping

I want to use an `env` variable within Docker container.
By using a `Makefile`.
This variable only exists in Docker container.

I wrote a `Makefile` for reusing code in CICD pipeline.
But I have problems with right escaping of the passing variable.

**Makefile**

```
execute:
    @echo $(COMMAND)
    docker exec -it my-dev-container $(COMMAND)
```

**Empty result of Makefile**

```
$ make execute COMMAND="bash -c 'echo $VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'"
bash -c echo
<< EMPTY >>
```

**Expected result of Makefile:**

```
$ make execute COMMAND="bash -c 'echo $VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'"
I_AM_A_VARIABLE_VALUE_WITHIN_THE_CONTAINER
```

**Without Makefile it's working:**

```
docker exec -it my-dev-container bash -c 'echo $VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'  
I_AM_A_VARIABLE_VALUE_WITHIN_THE_CONTAINER
```

Any ideas how to escape the string correctly?

Comment: For me, as for not-specialist in Makefile syntax, here is one additional point of uncertainty: correctness of passing CLI arguments to Makefile target internals. Are you sure COMMAND was passed correctly?

Comment: @ysurilov Good point. I added an echo statement above. Thank you.

Comment: Why introduce Make here?  Can you just `docker run --rm your-image sh -c '...'`, without the Make wrapper and without the requirement to already have a running container?

Comment: @DavidMaze Goal is run multipe containers in parallel and make it easy to run on-the-fly commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two escaping problems.  The first problem is you have to escape the `$` from the shell.  By using double-quotes you are not escaping the `$` from the shell: running `echo "$foo"` prints the value of the shell variable `foo`, it doesn't print the string `$foo`.

So when you run `make COMMAND="bash -c 'echo $VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'"`, the shell will expand `$VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER` before it even invokes make which is not what you want.  To avoid this you either have to use single-quotes or use a backslash:

```
make COMMAND="bash -c 'echo \$VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'"
```

Secondly, you need to escape the `$` from make because that's also a special character to make.  If you only use the above then make will expand `$V` as a make variable which also won't do what you want.  In make you escape a `$` by writing it twice, like `$$`

You have two choices: you can either add the escaping on the command line, like this:

```
make COMMAND="bash -c 'echo \$\$VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'"
```

Or if you're sure that you never want to expand anything in `COMMAND` as a make variable or function, you can use the [GNU Make `value` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Value-Function.html), like this:

```
execute:
         @echo $(value COMMAND)
         docker exec -it my-dev-container $(value COMMAND)
```

and running `make COMMAND="bash -c 'echo \$VARIABLE_ONLY_EXIST_IN_CONTAINER'"` will do what you want.